# Understanding of degree calcuation in quadrants

Tags: python, numpy, math

I found something in my search, which I don't understand. The goal is to read out the angle of a pointer in a pressure gauge. In my research, I found this example:

https://circuits-ninja.pl/reading-an-indication-from-an-analog-pressure-gauge-using-the-esp32-cam-module-with-an-ov2640-and-opencv-camera/

He's calculating the degree as follows:

```html
# Finding angle using the arc tan of y/x
res = np.arctan(np.divide(float(y_angle), float(x_angle)))
#Converting to degrees
res = np.rad2deg(res)

if x_angle > 0 and y_angle > 0:  #in quadrant I
    final_angle = 270 - res
if x_angle < 0 and y_angle > 0:  #in quadrant II
    final_angle = 90 - res
if x_angle < 0 and y_angle < 0:  #in quadrant III
    final_angle = 90 - res
if x_angle > 0 and y_angle < 0:  #in quadrant IV
    final_angle = 270 - res
```

I understand the reason of using quadrants in this case, but what i don't understand is why does he calculate 270 - res
if x_angle and y_angle > 0 and also calculate 270 - res if x_angle > 0 and y_angle < 0.
He's using the same formula for two different quadrants?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because `0` degrees is located, if placed on a two-dimensional surface, on (0,1)=(cos(90),sin(90)) instead of (1,0)=(cos(0),sin(0)). This means it has an offset of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler way:

```
 res = np.arctan2(float(y_angle), float(x_angle))
 #Converting to degrees
 res = np.rad2deg(res)
 if (res < 0):
     res += 360
```

That's all, `arctan2` will account for all cases including zero x

Answer (score 0):

Found it out my self. The reason why he is using 90 and 270 is because he split the pressure gauge in two half's. So the left one is calculated by 90 with the change of sign (- - = +) and that´s also for the other half. So he is each time in the correct quadrant with the change of sign.